# specifying a parameter instead of explicit value in process task

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I have a process task:

[image]

I'm wondering whether it's possible to pass something like this into it:

```
$Package::targetLocation
```

Thank you for your guidance,.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this with the `Expressions` tab, create a new `expression` against the `Arguments` property and assign this to your user variable.